# How to get the script of the stored procedure when a ddl trigger fires?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ddl

I'm writing ddl triggers for create and alter stored procedures.

For create stored procedure trigger, I want to get the script for the create statement. For alter stored procedure trigger, I want to get the new "create stored procedure" statement instead of alter statement.

Is there any way to do it? For the first one, I know eventdata() can do. But for the second one, I am not sure.

Comment: What technologies can you use?  TSQL? CLR? Other .NET?

Comment: So you don't like that the DDL trigger captures the ALTER command? Can't you convert it to a CREATE command using `STUFF(cmd, 1, 5, 'CREATE')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the DDL trigger, you can get the "after" image of the procedure using:

```
DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();

SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(
   @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
   + '.' + 
   @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
));
```

So you can assign that output to a variable and make it part of your insert (I assume you are logging this to some kind of DDL audit table). As I suggested in the comment, you can also do:

```
DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();

SELECT STUFF(@EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 
  1, 5, 'CREATE');
```

(These both assume your DDL trigger is limited to ALTER_PROCEDURE - otherwise you want to check the event type before you perform these operations.)

Comment: Just a couple of caveats: (1) this assumes you are capturing the "after" image before your code has a chance to call a rollback (in case you are trying to enforce any policies through the DDL trigger). (2) the STUFF approach depends on the first 5 characters being `ALTER`. If you do non-standard things like placing comments before the `CREATE/ALTER` statement, or put carriage returns or other white space before `CREATE/ALTER`, you'll have to adjust accordingly. The first method is safer in this regard.